# Vue.js reactive input conversion

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make a reactive % to px calculator for each layer in an array. (not actual %, but values between 0-1)

The px value is calculated by `% * output.width`

Currently when changing the % value it calculates the px value. I am trying to make the the px value an input rather than a span, so when it is changed it will then calculate the % value.

So change this: `<span>{{layer.settings.x * output.width}}px</span>` to something like this: `<input type="number" v-model="layer.settings.x * output.width">`

The % should always be the 'master value', so if `output.width` is changed, it should affect the px value and the % value should stay as is.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    output: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
      },
    layers: [{
      settings: {
        x: 1,
        y: 0.2
      }
    },
    {
      settings: {
        x: 0.5,
        y: 0.8
      }
    },
    {
      settings: {
        x: 0.25,
        y: 1,
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">

  <span>Output Resolution: </span>
  <input type="number" v-model="output.width">
  <span>x</span>
  <input type="number" v-model="output.height">

  <hr/>

  <div v-for="layer in layers" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  
    <span>Width</span>
    <input type="number" v-model="layer.settings.x">
    <span>{{layer.settings.x * output.width}}px</span>
    
    <br/>
    <span>Height</span>
    <input type="number" v-model="layer.settings.y">
    <span>{{layer.settings.y * output.height}}px</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Myabe you are using layer array wrong way. Try something like this:

```
<span>{{layers[0].settings.x * output.width}}px</span>
<span>{{layers[0].settings.y * output.height}}px</span>
```

Comment: @waldemarlce 
`<span>{{layer.settings.y * output.height}}px</span>` works correctly calculating the the px value. What i am trying to do is make it an input box instead of a span. Something like `<input type="number" v-model="layer.settings.y * output.height">`

Comment: @Jon And where you have defined layer object? You have defined only layers array.

Comment: @waldemarlce that is done by the v-for loop `<div v-for="layer in layers" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">`

Comment: @Jon Ok, I see it now.

Comment: @Jon But I still not understand what you mean with "input box".

Comment: @waldemarlce So instead of it being a span element, make it an input element - something along the lines of this: `<input type="number" v-model="layer.settings.y * output.height">`

Comment: @Jon And what do you want to do with this computed value? Do you want to set it as default value for input? Something like <input type="number" value="layer.settings.y * output.height">? Because I understand what you want - I dont understand why do you want to set this computed value as v-model.

Comment: @waldemarlce So when the value is changed it updates the the % value. Looking further into this it may require Computed Getters & Setters